# Apply function over every entry one table to every entry of another

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lapply, purrr

I would like to apply a function, `bandedlossfn` to all entries in `loss.tib` using every item in `bandstib`

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
n <- 5
loss <- rbeta(n, 1, 10) * 100

loss.tib <- loss %>% as_tibble %>% mutate(loss = value) %>% mutate(lossid = 
row_number()) %>% select(lossid, loss)
bandstib <- tibble(bandid = seq(4),
                   start = seq(0, 75, by = 25),
                   end = seq(25, 100, by = 25))

bandedlossfn <- function(loss, start, end) {
  pmin(end - start, pmax(0, loss - start))
}
```

As per the answer below the following code produces the calculation:

```
loss.tib %>% 
mutate(
  result = map(
    loss, ~ tibble(result = bandedlossfn(.x, bandstib$start, bandstib$end))
    )
    ) %>% unnest
```

However I'd like to include the `bandid` as the index within the map function and additionally `filter(!near(result,0))` with the map function.

The result should be:

```
lossid  loss    bandid  result
1   21.6691088  1   21.6691088  
2   6.9390647   1   6.9390647   
3   0.5822383   1   0.5822383   
4   5.5671643   1   5.5671643   
5   27.8237244  1   25.0000000  
5   27.8237244  2   2.8237244
```

Comment: Sorry, should be loss

Comment: and what would your expected output look like?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah - added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one possibility using `map2` from the `purrr` package:

```
bandstib %>% 
  mutate(result = map2(start, end, ~bandedlossfn(loss.tib[[1]], .x, .y)))
```

Depending on how you want your output to be you can continue from there by e.g. using `unnest`.

**EDIT**

Here is how you can apply it the otherway arround using `map` instead of `map2`:

```
loss.tib %>% 
  mutate(result = map(value, bandedlossfn, start = bandstib$start, end = bandstib$end)) %>%
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(bandid = rep(seq(4), n))
```

Comment: Hello @Cett, thanks how can I get this the other way round? I want to apply the bands to the loss table

Comment: hi, sorry, i misunderstood your question. I updated my answer

Comment: that's great! how can I include the `bandid` when I unnest?

Comment: I included this to. 
Depending on your exact data it would probably make more sense to include the bandid as an output `bandedlossfn`.

Comment: Ok this does it. However, my loss.tib has 30m rows so I'd like to index and filter results != 0 within the map function itself. Not sure if you have a quick solution or if I should ask as another question.

Comment: probably ask another question or modify this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192171/discussion-between-cettt-and-vincent-risington).