# Index list within map function

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr, purrr

This is a continuation from the previous question: 
[Apply function over every entry one table to every entry of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783462/apply-function-over-every-entry-one-table-to-every-entry-of-another/55783548?noredirect=1#comment98238950_55783548)

I have the following tables `loss.tib` and `bandstib` and function `bandedlossfn`:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
n <- 5
loss.tib <- tibble(lossid = seq(n),
                   loss = rbeta(n, 1, 10) * 100)

bandstib <- tibble(bandid = seq(4),
                   start = seq(0, 75, by = 25),
                    end = seq(25, 100, by = 25))

bandedlossfn <- function(loss, start, end) {
  pmin(end - start, pmax(0, loss - start))
}
```

It is possible to apply this function over `loss.tib` using `bandstib` as arguments:

```
loss.tib %>% 
mutate(
  result = map(
    loss, ~ tibble(result = bandedlossfn(.x, bandstib$start, 
bandstib$end))
    )
    ) %>% unnest
```

However, I would like to add an index within map as follows:

```
loss.tib %>% 
mutate(
  result = map(
    loss, ~ tibble(result = bandedlossfn(.x, bandstib$start, 
bandstib$end)) %>% 
    mutate(bandid2 = row_number())
    )
    ) %>% unnest
```

But it does not seem to work as intended.
I also want to add `filter(!near(result,0))` within the map function too for efficient memory management.

The result I'm expecting is:

```
lossid  loss    bandid  result
1   21.6691088  1   21.6691088  
2   6.9390647   1   6.9390647   
3   0.5822383   1   0.5822383   
4   5.5671643   1   5.5671643   
5   27.8237244  1   25.0000000  
5   27.8237244  2   2.8237244
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility:
you first nest `bandstib` and add it to `loss.tib`. This way the id sticks to your calculations:

```
bandstib <- tibble(bandid = seq(4),
                   start = seq(0, 75, by = 25),
                   end = seq(25, 100, by = 25)) %>% 
  nest(.key = "data")

set.seed(1)
n <- 5
result <- tibble(loss = rbeta(n, 1, 10) * 100) %>% 
  bind_cols(., slice(bandstib, rep(1, n))) %>%
  mutate(result = map2(loss, data, ~bandedlossfn(.x, .y$start, .y$end))) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Comment: Thanks @Cettt, I guess that obviates the need for the map function altogether... `result <- loss.tib %>% bind_cols(., slice(bandstib, rep(1, n))) %>% unnest %>% 
  mutate(result = bandedlossfn(loss, start, end)) %>% filter(!near(result,0))`. I was looking to do this without creating a larger than necessary tibble and applying the filtering within the map. But it works.

Comment: Ok after playing around a bit, this seems to do the trick... `loss.tib %>% 
mutate(result = map(
  loss, ~ tibble(result = bandedlossfn(.x, bandstib$start, bandstib$end)) %>% 
    mutate(bandid = seq(bandstib %>% nrow())) %>% 
    filter(!near(result, 0)))) %>% unnest`